# Ruby Regex for Json in Chef Recipe

Tags: json, ruby, regex, chef-infra

From `zabbix-api` login I have this output:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":"4b79a399f043fa44c5653bee3ecb346d","id":0}
```

I'm trying to parse using the code above in ruby:

```
command_out = shell_out(command).stdout.to_s
node.default['zabbix_server']['zabbix_auth'] = command_out.lines.grep(/"(result)":"((\\\"|[^"])*)"/)
```

how can I grab only the `"4b79a399f043fa44c5653bee3ecb346d"` ?

Comment: Parse the JSON and get the value: `JSON.parse(s)["result"]`

Comment: FWIW: `'{"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":"4b79a399f043fa44c5653bee3ecb346d","id":0}'[/(?<="result":").*?(?=")/] #⇒ "4b79a399f043fa44c5653bee3ecb346d"`.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually handling a [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON), which is a data format like XML or YAML.
Luckily enough, you can rely on the `JSON` gem, developed to parse a standard JSON.

Here is how you can use it:

```
require 'JSON'

my_json = '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":"4b79a399f043fa44c5653bee3ecb346d","id":0}'

a = JSON.parse(my_json)
p a['result']
```

and the output is:

> "4b79a399f043fa44c5653bee3ecb346d"